# Vision - is Bates method really able to restore one's vision?

Tags: eye, ophthalmology, effectiveness

Recently I learned about [the Bates method](http://www.seeing.org/techniques/) but it looks kinda fantasy for me (don't want to offend anyone). Are there people who followed these guides and succeeded in restoring (at least partially) their vision?

Comment: "restore vision" - what is the underlying pathology? Why does the patient have no (or reduced) vision?

Comment: @rumtscho personally I interested in curing myopia, but the method is stated to help with hypermetropia and astigmatism as well.